# Radeon X1600 Idles at 70 Degrees

Tags: lubuntu, mac, radeon, macbook-pro

I recently acquired an early 2006 Macbook Pro (Core Duo) with a mobility Radeon X1600. I installed 32-bit Lubuntu on it. The GPU is detected and identified correctly, and seems to work okay. But it's unpleasant to use the laptop because it runs so hot all the time, even when I'm just sitting at the desktop. Is there another driver I can install? I already checked for proprietary drivers but Lubuntu came up empty.

Comment: This is pretty much how Macbook Pros from that era roll. They have a lot of grunt, and as they age the thermal grease (which wasn't applied very well in some production runs anyway) used to draw heat away from the cores dries up. Linux or OS X, these are going to run hot.

Comment: Thanks, think it's a mix of that and the fact that the left fan was going out. Sounds like I have some work to do!

Comment: Oh, if the fan isn't allowed to run full bore when the cores are spun up, it is going to run hotter, yeah. As long as the fans are spinning and the air routes are clear, these models will get hot, even on the bottom. But they should just be lap tolerable. I know mine needs all the cores reseated with fresh grease, but the fans spin OK, so I put up with it.

Comment: Okay, opened it up, put new thermal paste in, not even a degree of difference. And both fans are spinning again, for the time being. I think the mesa driver is to blame as the temps seem fine in OS X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who has this problem, I figured out what it is. AMD no longer provides drivers for the graphics card in this machine, and the open source drivers Ubuntu uses are too inefficient for the MBP's tiny fans to keep up. The solution would be to somehow find proprietary AMD drivers, or install an older distro that comes with better ATI support.